# I'm trying to use undetected_chromedriver for my project. Trying to figure out the syntax to use xpath. Using that UC to bypass cloudflare ddos

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to use undetected_chromedriver for my project. Trying to figure out the syntax to use xpath. Using that UC to bypass cloudflare ddos. Below is the code which is an amalgamation of my other simpler scripts. I'm learning to automate using python.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import win32gui, win32con
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver.exe')

driver = uc.Chrome()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
driver.get('https://www.website.com/admin')
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)

#box = driver.find_element_by_xpath
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="email"]').send_keys('email.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('password')

driver.close()
```